# How to dynamically load and unload a native DLL file?

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke

I have a buggy third-party DLL files that, after some time of execution, starts throwing the access violation exceptions. When that happens I want to reload that DLL file. How do I do that?

Comment: How about loading the dll into a proxy process and terminate the whole process? Usually a process is considered broken after access violations.

Comment: How to do that? I heard very little about AppDomains. Can you please post some example?

Comment: Since it's a native dll AppDomains won't help you. You need to have a second process that loads the dll and then uses some form of inter process communication to transfer calls between processes. .net remoting might be one way. But I haven't done that myself.

Comment: Looks like Stecya's solution is much simpler.

Comment: Expecting a clean unload and reload from a dll that already has corrupted the memory so much that it throws access violation is not something I like. The dll lost track of which of its pointers are still valid. How should it free its memory cleanly on unload?

Comment: Access violation errors are fatal in nature. I doubt you can catch them using try catch handlers and then take some corrective measure.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try this

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string libname);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);

//Load
IntPtr Handle = LoadLibrary(fileName);
if (Handle == IntPtr.Zero)
{
     int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
     throw new Exception(string.Format("Failed to load library (ErrorCode: {0})",errorCode));
}

//Free
if(Handle != IntPtr.Zero)
        FreeLibrary(Handle);
```

If you want to call functions first you must create delegate that matches this function and then use WinApi `GetProcAddress`

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
private static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string lpProcName); 


IntPtr funcaddr = GetProcAddress(Handle,functionName);
YourFunctionDelegate function = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(funcaddr,typeof(YourFunctionDelegate )) as YourFunctionDelegate ;
function.Invoke(pass here your parameters);
```

Comment: And how to call my dll functions? When I declare them as `DllImport` this approach doesn't work

Comment: Did you resolve this?
can you provide some code snippe of the native code? how should the native code be declared and how does the delegate look? Thanks

Comment: @Poma Did you get this working ? Can you please tell me how to get the GetDelegateForFunctionPointer working ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a worker process that communicates via COM or another IPC mechanism. Then when the DLL dies, you can just restart the worker process.

Answer (score 0):

Load the dll, call it, and then unload it till it's gone.

I've adapted the following code from the VB.Net example [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robgruen/archive/2004/11/12/256199.aspx).

> ```
>   [DllImport("powrprof.dll")]
>   static extern bool IsPwrHibernateAllowed();
>
>   [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
>   static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);
>
>   [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
>   static extern bool LoadLibraryA(string hModule);
>
>   [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
>   static extern bool GetModuleHandleExA(int dwFlags, string ModuleName, ref IntPtr phModule);
>
>   static void Main(string[] args)
>   {
>         Console.WriteLine("Is Power Hibernate Allowed? " + DoIsPwrHibernateAllowed());
>         Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
>         Console.ReadKey();
>   }
>
>   private static bool DoIsPwrHibernateAllowed()
>   {
>         LoadLibraryA("powrprof.dll");
>         var result = IsPwrHibernateAllowed();
>         var hMod = IntPtr.Zero;
>         if (GetModuleHandleExA(0, "powrprof", ref hMod))
>         {
>             while (FreeLibrary(hMod))
>             { }
>         }
>         return result;
>   }
> ```