# AssemblyResolve event for native dll

Tags: c#, dll, .net-assembly

I have an C# application which use native dll. I would like to choose location of the dll to be loaded after application start according to some conditions.

There is a possibility to add a handler [AssemblyResolve](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve(v=vs.110).aspx)  for managed assemblies. I tested it, but it is not working for native libraries. Is there any solution for native library like AssemblyResolve event?

Comment: Check this link might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6452997/1845593

Comment: Yes, it is working fine.